# How to avoid beans which are not required in Spring during component scan?

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my project we have around 30 beans in a package. I want to load only a Details bean from that package using component scan and how to avoid other beans loading ? In the below example i am interested in only on Details bean other beans not required to load? But the below one is not working?

```
Example :

com.spring.test
Student.java
Details.java
Contacts.java

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={,"com.spring.test"},
includeFilters=@Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.spring.test.Details"), excludeFilters=@Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.spring.test.*^((?!Details).)*$"))
public class AppConfig {


}
```

Comment: Don't put 30 unrelated beans in the same package then.

Comment: it is already defined in my project i should not move to another package

Comment: Then don't scan and just create an `@Bean` method for it. Also the fact that those `Student` and `Contacts` classes are in there makes me even wonder you should even scan those. Those look more like domain objects then services etc. to me.

Answer (score 1):

Add @Lazy in your bean definition or add @Lazy at class level to load all beans lazily.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java config file should be marked with `@Configuration` annotation. After then your Spring application loads configuration from this file.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` to the component or the bean, in order to not create it on boot time (unless another bean autowired it). But with this solution your bean will not be a singleton which mean that every place you are autowire the component, a new instance will be created.